# Phrase for a child moving around -- "ritching around"?

Tags: expressions

Whenever a child was fidgeting or moving around, my grandmother would tell them "stop ritching around!" When I used this phrase recently, my wife told me that it was not an English expression, and I was surprised that I could not find it on Google.

Is "ritching around" an English expression for a child moving around? Is it instead some Pennsylvania Dutch dialect that my grandmother picked up from learning English in Pennsylvania?

Comment: Never heard it.  There was a fair amount of Dutch blood in our family, on my father's side, but pretty far back, and I don't recall that any words or expressions made it through.

Comment: Could it have just been a slightly altered pronunciation of "reaching"?

Comment: @MortimerBallsack I don't think so, but I suppose if nobody else has heard of this phrase then altered pronunciation could be a plausible explanation.

Comment: No idea of the origin, but in my family we would have said "ooching around" (not even sure how to spell it).

Comment: @ewormuth Interesting -- it seems like this is a variant on "rootching around" and probably also derives from Pennsylvania Dutch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I live in PA, and it's a very common word among the PA Dutch (I've picked up a great many strange words and expressions from them.)

It's not quite "ritching"; the first syllable's vowel sound is more like the *oo* in *book*. So I would spell it "rootching", but, yes. It is equivalent to [*squirming*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/squirm):

> a change of position that does not entail a change of location -TFD

Synonymous with fidgeting, wiggling, etc.

Comment: Aha -- your pronunciation tip solved the mystery! "rootch" returns a handful of Google results like [this one](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rootch), indicating it's a Pennsylvania Dutch word meaning to squirm.

Comment: Wow! I'm really surprised to see it online. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Ritching around was used in my family too! By my grandmother whose mom came from Bavaria. German roots maybe?
Yes. I found the German word rutsch which can be used to mean stop sliding (rutsching) your bum around.

Answer (score 0):

never heard of it myself. I would say quit **flailing** about

Comment: I think a more direct translation of how she used it was "quit moving around" (aka the action could be less significant than flailing). I guess with this question I'm most interested in whether "ritching around" is an expression.